# Newbie with "classname" object

Tags: java

I am learning java at the moment and I am struggling to understand how this code actually works.

considering this code:

```
    private Customer findCutomer(String customerName) {
   'for(int i=0; i<this.customers.size(); i++) {
        Customer checkedCustomer = this.customers.get(i);
        if(checkedCustomer.getName().equals(customerName)) {
            return checkedCustomer;
        }
    }
```

I don't really understand how Customer checkedCustomer works here.  All I know is I have a Customer class, and this code is making checkedCustomer as an object to get the index number of a customer from arraylist.  But what does this object have inside?  There is a constructor inside Customer class and it has name and amount as parameter.  Does it mean checkedCustomer has some sort of name and properties?  or its just a blank object?  If that is the case, why would I need to create this object then ?  Thanks for helping out a newbie here.

edit 1:
Thanks for the replies.  Sorry for all the confusion I made.  Its pretty hard for me to explain what I dont know since I am very confused.  These codes are from my instructor, and it works.  I just dont understand why and when we have to create an object.
sometimes, I will see this  `private Branch findBranch(String branchName) {`, in this case, from my understanding , Branch is class, and he made a variable as findBranch.  What is the difference between private Branch findBranch vs private double/int/boolean findBranch?  For the question,   Customer checkedCustomer = this.customers.get(i);, what is Customer, the class, doing here?  What is the difference vs double checkedCustomer, or String checkedCustomer..Thanks

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to say definitively, but this is how it looks to me: `customers` is an arraylist of Customer objects. The method iterates through all the Customer objects in the list to find the Customer object which has the same name field as the `customerName` argument.  `checkedCustomer` is a temporary holder variable to store the Customer object that the loop is currently on so that a comparison can be made. `checkedCustomer` is the Customer object that is returned by the method when a match is found. Finally... I don't think that method will compile.

Comment: It doesn't _get the index number_; you _have_ the index number (inside `i`) and are using it _to get the `Customer` object from the list_. (Note that the for-each loop `for (Customer candidate: customers)` is cleaner.)

Comment: Anything that you can assign to Customer is an object. You can either get from the ArrayList or create in the same line. In Java the difinition of the Customer class itself doesn't create any objects. It's a prototype of the object. And you create objects usung a constructor.

Comment: Pendant: `checkedCustomer` is not an object. `checkedCustomer` *refers* to an object, but isn't the object itself.  The difference can be subtle, but try to keep it in mind as it will make your life easier to learn the right way.  Lots of issues later if you get those mixed up that you'll have to unlearn.